# Scala Spray Routing - two HTTP method directives executed for single request

Tags: scala, rest, spray

Here is my routing:

```
pathPrefix("event" / Segment / "user") { id =>
    pathEnd {
        put {
            dbService.addParticipant(id, user)
            complete("OK")
        } ~
        delete {
            dbService.removeParticipant(id, user)
            complete("OK")
        }
    }
} ~
```

When sending PUT or DELETE request to `http://localhost:9999/event/860852c4-768f-430e-9a9d-d1d35e86ede2/user` both method directives are executed - I mean `dbService.addParticipant(id, user)` and `dbService.removeParticipant(id, user)` are called. Could anyone explain me where is the problem here?

I do not see how this differs from [official spray example](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-routing/):

```
// extract URI path element as Int
pathPrefix("order" / IntNumber) { orderId =>
  pathEnd {
    // method tunneling via query param
    (put | parameter('method ! "put")) {
      // form extraction from multipart or www-url-encoded forms
      formFields('email, 'total.as[Money]).as(Order) { order =>
        complete {
          // complete with serialized Future result
          (myDbActor ? Update(order)).mapTo[TransactionResult]
        }
      }
    } ~
    get {
      // JSONP support
      jsonpWithParameter("callback") {
        // use in-scope marshaller to create completer function
        produce(instanceOf[Order]) { completer => ctx =>
          processOrderRequest(orderId, completer)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Things inside of `complete {}` are run for every request. See http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/advanced-topics/understanding-dsl-structure/#understanding-extractions. As this is the single most asked question for spray you will find lots of information on the spray mailing list about it e.g. in this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/spray-user/confusion/spray-user/6T4BT2O5u00/nFaep0TeOWoJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jrudolph [pointed out](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/advanced-topics/understanding-dsl-structure/#understanding-extractions), code inside non-leaf extraction directive (like inside `pathPrefix("order" / IntNumber) { orderId =>` as it takes `orderId` parameter that is gonna be extracted from request) is executed per every request regardless wether or not directives inside are hitting the route. Code inside leaf-directive (like `complete`) is executed only when route matches.

To achieve what you probably want, just move your `dbService.addParticipant` inside `complete`:

```
pathPrefix("event" / Segment / "user") { id =>
    pathEnd {
        put {
            complete {
              dbService.addParticipant(id, user)
              "OK"
            }
        } ~
        delete {
            complete {
              dbService.removeParticipant(id, user)
              "OK"
            }
        }
    }
}
```